# What could speaker mean by asking "Oh, it is, is it?"

Tags: meaning, british-english, syntax

I found this in English syntax textbook.
What could speaker mean by using "is it" instead of "isn't"

**The whole example goes like this:**

> My advice to you is to wait.
>
> Unfortunately, the matter is rather urgent.
>
> Oh, it is, is it?

Comment: Why would the speaker use "isn't it?"

Comment: Isn't this how these tag questions work, asking always the opposite of the previous sentence? So like "It was him, wasn't it?" "You aren't sure, are you?" "It is what it is, isn't it?"

Comment: Not always - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone says, about something just said to them, a statement of the form *pronoun+verb 'to be'* (he is/you are/I am/they are/you were/it is, etc), followed by the *same statement reversed* as a positive question, they are expressing an emotion such as anger, disbelief, or scepticism, or maybe just surprise:

> Daughter: My boyfriend's a genius. Father: He is, is he?
>
> Son: Dad, you're a fool. Father: I am, am I?
>
> Neighbour: My car's better than yours. Me: It is, is it?
>
> Person: I slept with your wife by accident, not on purpose. Me: You did, did you?

Sometimes we say "Oh" at the beginning to add more emphasis.

> Daughter: You're going to pay $50,000 for my wedding! Father: Oh, I
> am, am I? Well, I'd better start learning how to rob banks without being caught, because that's the only way I'll be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks, so is it purely rhetorical or is answer sometimes expected?

Comment: Could be either. The daughter might say "Yes", and provide examples of her boyfriend's great intelligence, or she might not. often the other person is being expected to justify their statement, or shut up.

Comment: If the question is followed by (often sarcastic) remarks, then probably no reply is expected.

Comment: Although I am definitely not the father/husband/car owner in those examples, there is something a bit familiar about them....